# MYSQL Result consisted more than one row when using mysql function in where clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a stored procedure (Function) that calculates product price.

This is my function :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getWinnerPriceByProductId`(
    `p_product_id` INT


)
RETURNS float
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_winner_price FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_product_plan VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT ps.plan INTO v_product_plan FROM product_supplier ps WHERE ps.product_id = p_product_id AND ps.winner = 1;

    IF v_product_plan = 'Plan AB' THEN
        SELECT ps.wholesale_price INTO v_winner_price FROM product_supplier ps WHERE ps.product_id = p_product_id AND ps.winner = 1 LIMIT 1;
    ELSE
            SELECT ps.price INTO v_winner_price FROM product_supplier ps WHERE ps.product_id = p_product_id AND ps.winner = 1 LIMIT 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN v_winner_price;      
END
```

Now When i simply call this function like :

```
Select getWinnerPriceByProductId(1);
```

Then it returns the correct result.

But When I try using it in the where clause like :

```
SELECT * FROM products p where getWinnerPriceByProductId(p.id) BETWEEN 1 AND 100;
```

Then I get a error saying :

> The Result Consisted more than one rows.

If the result consisted of more than one rows then should not the same be the case when the function is called as in the first case ? Why is this only happening when I use the function in some query ? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the first query, it returned 1 row since you have declared limit in stored procedure, In the second query, it also returned 1 row, but since you have filtered to in between records that's why it returned more than 1 row. Also, you have specific `p.id` value on your first query where it specifically filtered 1 record

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @tcadidot0 mysql 5.7

Comment: what is the result of your function that returns 1?

Comment: @James You mean in the first query ?  The first query returns a float and it is the desired result.

Comment: So what you are trying to do in 2nd query?

Comment: @James trying to filter out the products whose price are between 1 and 100, but I need to calculate the product price on the fly.

Comment: The query works if it is as `SELECT * FROM products where getWinnerPriceByProductId(1) BETWEEN 1 AND 100;`

Comment: @James yes it does. But i want to calculate and check the price of each products on the fly. Is this not the right approach ?

Comment: Yeah, its wrong, If you see @jned29 comment you can see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Finally, your query will just selects all the entries in the table, multiple times ex: `SELECT * FROM products where 1.4 between 1 and 100;` so condition matches then it displays whole table. Again `SELECT * FROM products where 5.5 between 1 and 100;` again the cycle repeats... is this what you need?

Comment: @James Thanks for clearing this up for me. I need something like, select all columns from table if the price is between the range. Can you suggest me the right approach ?

Comment: *if the price is between the range* but you are parsing a range of price in your 2nd query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no need of function to be created. Will edit this answer once OP gives more info.

```
-- function can be replaced into simple join query
select case when ps.plan='Plan AB' then ps.wholesale_price else ps.price end as 'winner_price' 
from product_supplier ps
join product p on ps.product_id=p.id
where ps.winner=1 
and p.id=1; -- this is what you are parsing into the function
```

Comment: Thanks.I think this is the most appropriate answer for the question. But as I have simplified the question for clarity, but in actual scenario the price calculation involves much more calculation with margins and commissions. I think i would need to make a function in such case. I would love to know how to use a function to compare it's result inside a where clause.

Comment: Look the doc on cursor if it helps you refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT * FROM products where getWinnerPriceByProductId(p.id) BETWEEN 1 AND 100;

What is **p.id** we did not create an alias for this? could you please make sure this SP return on 1 column getWinnerPriceByProductId(p.id).

Comment: I added the alias in the question, that was a typo. And yes the function returns a single row when called as in the first query. And moreover i have used a limit 1 in every SELECT INTO cases.